# make a put with mechanize in ruby and rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize-ruby

I try make a put in a rails server I get this error:
'send_request_with_body': undefined method 'bytesize' for # (NoMethodError)
this is the ruby code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.basic_auth('user@gmail.com', '12345678')



a = agent.put('http://localhost:3000/thermostats/26.json',{ "thermostat[serial]" => "1",   "thermostat[temperature]" => 50,   "thermostat[humidity]" => 122222, "thermostat[user_id]" => 6 })
```

and this is the code of the controller you want to do put

```
# PATCH/PUT /thermostats/1.json


def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @thermostat.update(thermostat_params)
    @thermostat.history_thermostats.create(temperature:@thermostat.temperature, humidity: @thermostat.humidity, energy: @thermostat.energy)
    format.html { redirect_to @thermostat, notice: 'Thermostat was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @thermostat.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

end
```

Comment: Read the documentation for #put, the second argument should be a string, not a hash: https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize.rb#L533

Comment: What should I put in "entity"?, 
Is the name of the controller?

Comment: Did you figured out the answer?

Comment: I could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of Lee Jarvis' answer. This worked for me.

> @agent.put(uri, "{\"key\": \"val\",\"key\": \"val\"}", {"Content-Type"
>   => "application/json"})